# How to define an empty interface in *.proto file?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I need such a structure in the Go:

```golang
type SomeStruct struct{
    Foo bool
    Bar interface{}
}
```

How to define an empty interface in *.proto file? If this is not possible then how to solve the problem with the description of a field of variable type *.proto file?

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf  does not support generic types.
Because I know all the possible types I can use `Oneof`  : [Oneof](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#oneof)

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes is working around that by using `bytes`.

```rb
syntax = "proto3";

message sample {
    bytes object = 1;
}
```

Then you need to do some extra steps when receiving or sending the message. You need to marshal the field first and assign it to a byte field on your struct.

```
type object struct {
    N int
}

type Sample struct {
    Object []byte
}

func main() {
    var s Sample
    o := object{N: 1}
    s.Object, _ = json.Marshal(o)
}
```

You can check some of their type definitions to see that. I.e. https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/b98f264fe39f5b5393bf918d8c16f86527965f1c/admission/v1/types.go#L101.

Comment: Well, if its good enough for K8s it is good enough for me. ✌️